# I've updated a $rootScope varible, but why I still got the old value when I access it in beforeLeave event handler?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, rootscope

The codes in the controller of a data entry page:

```js
.controller("MobileInputCtrl", function ($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.$watch("myForm.$dirty", function (newVal) {
    $rootScope.isDirty = newVal;
  });
})
```

I've put a testing `<div>` on this page to show the value of `$rootScope.isDirty`. It proved out that the value had been correctly updated to `true`.

The codes in the `$ionicView.beforeLeave` handler registered in the `run()` method in the top module:

```js
angular.module("app", [])

.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $rootScope) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
    $rootScope.$on("$ionicView.beforeEnter", function (event, view) {
      $rootScope.isDirty = false;
    });

    $rootScope.$on("$ionicView.beforeLeave", function (event, view) {
      alert($rootScope.isDirty); // still shows false
    });
  });
});
```

I've seen through the testing `<div>` that `isDirty` had been correctly updated to `true`. But when I leave the page, why the alert popup still show the value as `false`? I'm very confused about this. Are there two `isDirty` variables behind the scene???

Comment: It looks like you need to understand what the angular digest cycle does. Take a look at  docs for scope.apply, and applyAsync and it should give you some insight into what you are seeing.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are right, I'm not familiar with that, which may be the core part of Angular. I'll read the docs thoroughly. Anyway, in short, do you have any suggestions on modifying the above codes to make it work?

Comment: Also change $rootScope.$on to $scope.$on